# insulated charged object making contact with an open circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, insulators, short-circuits

I have a circuit in where an "object" is going to be placed instantaneously in the gap of the circuit, but the object will not touch the wire on either side of the gap.

[image]

The objects has two blocks of plastic ( one on the left with negative charge and one on the right with positive charge)

Now, my question is, would the charges in the segment of the wire to the right of the gap experience any electric force when the block is in place?  And my second question is would the charges in the electric circuit move?
In my opinion I don't think they will move because they have an insulator but correct me if i'm wrong or please help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

If the ends of the wire are attached to the plates of a parallel-plate capacitor, and the charged object passes through the large gap between the plates, it will induce charges on the plates of the capacitor. This will cause a transient current to flow in the circuit for a very short time. When the object leaves the gap the transient current will flow again in the opposite direction, to neutralise the induced charges on the capacitor plates.

This effect will be strongest if the plates are far apart and the insulated charges are on plates of the same size and they pass very close to the capacitor plates.